# Blowing-up a singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have this system of ODEs:

$$x'=-y+ \mu x(x^2+y^2)$$

$$y'=x+ \mu y(x^2+y^2)$$

I already find that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the only singular point is $(0,0)$. So I have to blow-up the singularity to find the phase diagram. For that I use polar coordinates, the problem is that I get a system of the form

$$r'=\mu r^3$$ 
$$r^2\theta'=r^2$$

so $\theta'$ is never zero, but I'm pretty sure that the system has at least 2 singular points, any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I never tought about that, thanks. I'm going to check the cases for $\mu>0$, $\mu<0$ and $\mu=0$ then.

Comment: The system has only one singular point (the origin) and your equations in the polar coordinates seems to be correct. So the problem is with your confidence „that the system has at least 2 singular points“ — this is just a wrong statement (and you prove that it is wrong!).